# Operate on data or simulate user input?

Tags: blender

I'm trying to write my first blender script to import a BVH animation and copy the keyframes from the imported rig to an existing rig.  It seems to me there are two ways to do this:

1. Operate on the data directly, by looping over bpy.data.objects[rig].animation_data.action.fcurves.keyframes and somehow copying them into the corresponding data structure on the existing rig
2. Simulate the way a user would do it by setting the context to a 3D view, importing the mesh, setting the context to the curves editor, selecting all, copying, switching back to 3D view, selecting the existing rig, switching back to curves again and pasting the data

Number 1 sounds like the right way to me, but looking at the API it seems that it's more geared towards number 2.  Is that right?  The Blender way of doing things would be to set the selection and use the copy/paste operators?

I'd like to know which is the idiomatic way of doing things in Blender.